# NSArray to stay valid always

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

i have an app that on the init method , i need to load an array with many backgrounds, and than this array will stay valid during this scene, till i leave it(and release it in dealloc)

in my init i have this :

```
backgrounds=[ [NSArray alloc]  initWithObjects:BACK,BACK1,BACK2,BACK3,BACK4,BACK5,BACK6,BACK7,BACK8,BACK9, nil];

    int imageDelta=1;
    for (background in backgrounds)  
        {
            background.position=ccp(240*imageDelta,160);
            imageDelta=imageDelta+2;
            [self addChild:background ];
        }
     //release backgrounds here ????
```

now, my question is, **can** i and **should** i release `backgrounds` now ??
i still need this array to be valid during the code .
it seems i didnt really understood arrays .

thanks a lot.

Comment: do you need backgrounds array outside the init function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you shouldn't release that backgrounds array in the init method because it's an instance variable. You are correct in saying that it should only release it in dealloc, which is when you have finished with it.

If you release that backgrounds array in you init method you won't be able to access it again after that because it would be a deallocated instance. I take it that the reason you have the backgrounds array as an instance variable is because you want to access it again?

Answer (score 0):

No, cause background is not being allocated, so you dont need to care about it.

If you dont explicit allocate a variable, its marked as autorelease

Comment: its allocated, the NSArray is alloced, havnt you see ? or i didnt understand something? , i guess when the word alloc is there, release needs to be appeared ..

Comment: It is allocated: [NSArray alloc]

Answer (score 0):

if you need backgrounds array as an instance variable (you will need the variable durring the object life), so you have to release it in dealoc.

if you need backgrounds array only in the init method, change it to a local variable and use:

```
NSArray *backgrounds = [NSArray initWithObjects:BACK,BACK1,BACK2,BACK3,BACK4,BACK5,BACK6,BACK7,BACK8,BACK9, nil];
```

so you don't have to care about it, as its an autorelease.